# Forcing NN to have fixed or identity output in a region of state space

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions

I have a transition system defined over state space $X$,
with a transition function $f: X \to X$.
Let us assume my task is to learn a function $G: X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $G$ is decreasing, i.e. $G(x) > G(f(x))$, on a subset of transitions in $X$. My loss function is something of the following form:
$$ L(x) = \text{ReLU}\big(G(x) - G(f(x)) + \epsilon\big) $$
for some manually defined $\epsilon$.
We can also define $L$ using sigmoid instead of ReLU.

One case that I have seen during experimentation is
that if I also want $G$ to keep 0
on the two end points of some transitions,
the model I get in the end is something that always predicts 0.

Another case is
where I want $f$ to be strictly decreasing on a transition $x_1 \to x_2$,
and *only simple-decreasing*, i.e. $G(x) \geq G(f(x))$,
on $x_2 \to x_1$.
Using a loss function similar to what I described above
(having $\epsilon = 0$ to encode simple decreasing), I observed
that I can include only one of
$x_1 \to x_2$ and $x_2 \to x_1$ in my training data;
otherwise, $G$ is not learned *properly*
on at least one of the transitions.

Is there a theoretical ML explanation behind this?
Can I fix this issue by having a different loss function,
e.g., not in the form of $\text{ReLU}(\dots$)?
My current hack is
to include only one of $x_1 \to x_2$ and $x_2 \to x_1$
in my training data;
but this approach limits us to
a rather simple set of transition systems.

This question comes from a research project;
that is why it lacks context and is over-simplified at points.

Comment: Why not use an ordinary loss function like MSE and an identity function output?

Comment: @Sycorax you mean for the simple-decreasing?